# How to remove white space in a multicolumn table?

Tags: tables, margins

Im making a multi-column table. However some of the table go out the paper margin, which I believe due to the white space in between column.
May I know how to solve this problem.

The code is as below.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} \sisetup{table-format=2.1}


\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
\caption{Some caption}
\scriptsize 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            S[table-format=0.0]
            S[table-format=0.0]
            S[table-format=0.0]
            S[table-format=0.1]
            %%%% Overal metrics
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            %%
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
        }

        \toprule
%       & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\bfseries Emissions} \\
%       \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Study}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Method}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[tl]{Num. of\\ subjects}}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dataset}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Overall metrics}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Class-wise sensitivity} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Class-wise sensitivity} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){5-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-14}\cmidrule(lr){15-19}

        &&&
        & {Acc.}
        & {$\kappa$}
        & {MF1}
        & {Sens.}
        & {Spec.}
        %%% Class-wise sensitivity
        & {W}
        & {N1}
        & {N2} 
        & {N3}
        & {REM}
        %%% Class-wise selectivity
        & {W}
        & {N1}
        & {N2} 
        & {N3}
        & {REM}\\
        \midrule
        \cite{Mendonca2019} & {ARNN +RNN}    & {90}& {test} & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00  & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00  &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &{--} & 98.00  \\
        \cite{Mendonca2019} & {ABC}    & {90}& {test} & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00  & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00  &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00  \\
            \cite{Mendonca2019} & {ABC}    & {90}& {test} & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & {--} & {--}   & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00  &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
    \centering` you can decrase the horizontal white space between columns so that your table will fit into the margins. However, I'd recommend either rortating the table or redesigning it as the font size is quite small.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I still wonder whether I can remove the white spacing between column so that it is possible to increase the font size further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the value of `\tabcolsep` to 3.5pt  does the job.

I took the liberty to simplify the code (I don't see why the 4 first columns have  the `S` type, so I replaced them with `c`). Also, I think it looks better to have their columns heads set with  `multirow`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} \sisetup{table-format=2.1}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\caption{Some caption}
\scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            *{4}{c}
            %%%% Overal metrics
            *{15}{S[table-format=2.2]}
        }

        \toprule
% & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\bfseries Emissions} \\
% \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
        \multirow{2.5}{*}{Study}
        & \multirow{2.5}{*}{Method}
        & \multirowcell{2.5}{Num. of\\ subjects}
        & \multirow{2.5}{*}{Dataset}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Overall metrics}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Class-wise sensitivity}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Class-wise sensitivity} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){5-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-14}\cmidrule(lr){15-19}

        &&&
        & {Acc.}
        & {$\kappa$}
        & {MF1}
        & {Sens.}
        & {Spec.}
        %%% Class-wise sensitivity
        & {W}
        & {N1}
        & {N2}
        & {N3}
        & {REM}
        %%% Class-wise selectivity
        & {W}
        & {N1}
        & {N2}
        & {N3}
        & {REM}\\
        \midrule
        \cite{Mendonca2019} & ARNN +RNN & 90 & test & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &{--} & 98.00 \\
        \cite{Mendonca2019} & ABC & 90 & test & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00 \\
            \cite{Mendonca2019} & ABC & 90& test & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & {--} & {--} & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00& 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00 & 98.00 &98.00 & 98.00 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: But, I still wonder whether I can remove the white spacing between column so that it is possible to increase the font size further

Comment: You can't remove it completely for readability reasons. However, setting `\tabcolsep` to `2.8 pt`, you can have \footnotesize`. Down to 1.8pt, you can have `\small`. Less would not be sensible: 1.8 pt means the white space between columns is twice that space (i.e. approximately, 1.25 mm).

Comment: @Bernhard, I suggest to remove the side bearings by using `{}@`. If you abbreviate "Num. of subjects" to "Num. Subj" and split "Dataset" over two lines ("Data-set"), you may gain some space.

Comment: @Sveining: That's a good idea. We can even remove the spacing between the 1st and 2nd columns, due to the particular contents of the columns. This way, one can have `3.2pt` in `footnotesize`, or `2pt` in `small`.

Comment: Dear Sveinung,
How to remove the side bearings by using {}@? Which part of the code I need to change?

Comment: Hi David, May I know how to remove the spacing between the 1st and 2nd columns?

Comment: To remove this spacing (and the left side bearing), in the table preamble, just replace `*{4}{c}` with `@{}c@{}*{3}{c}`.